# Issue when I run "grunt build"

Tags: gruntjs, yeoman

I am working with grunt and when I write "grunt build" my dist folder builds everything, except for the js files. I get the following message:

[image]

I'm guessing I have to edit my Gruntfile, but I'm not sure how to go about solving this.

My Gruntfile is long, but here is the uglify part:
[image]

Comment: Is `dist/scripts/scripts.js` correct path? Try to run `grunt uglify` with `--verbose`  key to verbose output.

Comment: What do I want the path to be? What does it mean by the destination was not written because src files were empty

Comment: please post your Gruntfile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What does it mean by the destination was not written because src files were empty

It means the files listed in `dist: {src:"<%config.app%>*"` were not created yet. Use the following process:

- Run copy and uglify manually and verbosely

  ```
  grunt copy:dist --verbose
  grunt uglify:dist --verbose
  ```
- If it works, reorganize the task in question in the `registerTask` method:

  ```
  grunt registerTask("build", ['copy:dist','uglify:dist']);
  ```
- Otherwise, dump the `<%config.app%>` path to make sure it is correct

  ```
  grunt.registerTask('dump', 'Dump Output', function(){ console.log(grunt.config.get() ) });
  ```

**References**

- [Grunt API: grunt.config.get](http://gruntjs.com/api/grunt.config#grunt.config.get)
- [Grunt Documentation: Using the CLI](http://gruntjs.com/using-the-cli)